# page controller

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I have a problem with removing unused pages from an array:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [descriptionsList count]; i++) {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
```

i'm adding objects with:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= [descriptionsList count]) return;
    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    DetailsView *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[DetailsView alloc] initWithElement:[descriptionsList objectAtIndex:page]
                                                 andFrame:CGRectMake(320*page, 0, 320, 420)];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (nil == controller.superview) {
        [scrollView addSubview:controller];
    }
}
```

and i'm using this to remove and create pages:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlUsed = NO;

    //load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < [descriptionsList count]; i++) {
        if (i < pageController.currentPage - 1 || i > pageController.currentPage + 1) {
            if ([viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] != nil) {
                [[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] release];
                [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
            }
        }
        else {
            [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
        }
    }
}
```

My app is crashing big time when i want to view page 3. Any advice on how should this be done? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which line or block of code the crash occurs in.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems:

- NSArrays can't store 'nil' objects, so your check for != nil will always succeed, so you don't need it
- You definitely should not be releasing the object in the array; You don't have a corresponding -retain message, and regardless, the array will automatically retain objects put into it, and release them when they're removed
- your nomenclature is a little confusing. You have an array called viewControllers, and an objected called controller, but these both appear to be views (since you're initWithFrame'ing them.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if ([viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] != nil)
```

will always evaluate as TRUE because the array is populated with NSNULL objects which do not evaluate to nil. The block executes even when there is a view stored at index. This block will populate your entire array with `NSNull` objects, wiping out all your views. Any subsequent call to the view will crash.

I think you've got a bad design here. You shouldn't be putting views into an Array. Instead, you need to have your ***data*** in an array and then populate reusable views based on what data should be displayed at any given time. Look at how 'UITable' displays itself with reusable 'UITableViewCells'.

Answer (score -1):

This approach with lazy loading i've got it from a good book in fact, but the sample was with very very simple views, and without releasing them. The pages initialization was made in the scrollViewDidScroll method, which was a total mess on the device with my content: a photo and 2 texts. And the memory used is crashing my app, that's why i want to keep loaded only 3 pages. Here's the updated code, but i can't release the object nor remove from view, so i get duplicates.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < [descriptionsList count]; i++) {
        if (i < pageController.currentPage - 1 || i > pageController.currentPage + 1) {
            DetailsView *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
            if ((NSNull *)controller != [NSNull null]) {
                if (nil != controller.superview) {
                    NSLog(@"remove from superview %d", i);
                    //[controller.superview removeFromSuperview];
                }
                [viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                [viewControllers insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:i];
                //[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"allocating %d", i);
            [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
        }
    }
}
```

So, will i be able to create my views in real time without flashes if i'm using only 2 reusable views? I've saw a sample with 2 views but said that the content must exist, and i'm not sure how good is to keep in memory about 15 pngs.